# Spark plugs problems with Honda Accord

Tags: honda, civic, accord

My 98 Honda Accord ex had spark plugs change the vehicle stills shakes bad [image]what can I do to fix this problem..

Comment: Welcome to the site! We appreciate you being here. If you could help us a little bit with what's going on? Did you change out the plugs or did you have someone do it for you? Does the vehicle have any codes? Is the Check Engine Light on? If you have the codes, can you share them with us? If not, can you get them read?

Comment: My 98 Honda keep misfiring on spark 1

Comment: According to the sheet, you've got multiple misfires on multiple cylinders. Really, the sheet doesn't tell us anything beyond your car having misfire codes. What work have you done to the car this far? Have you changed out the plugs?

Comment: Change the sparks plug and its still shaking bad I don't know what else to do

Comment: I'm going to get a tune up and oil change because my car still start up fine I just don't know what to do help......